# PHP pack() format for signed 32 int - big endian

Tags: php, pack

I am creating and then writing data to a file (a new 'ESRI Shape file') using PHP, fopen, fseek, pack etc. The file spec is here http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

The file spec states that the data written needs to be in a combination of the following:

- Integer: Signed 32-bit integer (4 bytes) - Big Endian
- Integer: Signed 32-bit integer (4 bytes) - Little Endian
- Double: Signed 64-bit IEEE double-precision floating point number (8 bytes) - Little Endian

I cant seem to find a pack() format that allows for these formats. I don't want to use a machine dependent format as this code may be running on a variety of platforms.

Can anyone advise on what format (or combination of formats) I need to use for these 3 formats?

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: could you not take a leaf out of encryption and use null byte pkcs padding instead of pack()

Comment: Alternatively you could maybe use [the PECL extension to read and write shapefiles](http://pecl.php.net/package/shape)?

Comment: @TML, Oh, I thought he said *for* PHP. Why is this tagged "Perl" at all?!?! And 'N' and 'V' will work perfectly fine to pack signed ints. Next time, test before contradicting someone!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tagged this as 'perl' as the PHP pack extension is very closely related to perl and the formats are broadly the same - i hoped that the issue could be resolved with a specific format.

Comment: I have spent a couple of hours trying to get the PECL extension working and have failed. I'l running a Ubuntu 12 server and am just getting errors on install. I can only assume that the extension is not compatible - last updated in 2009. Shame - it would have been very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check the endianness of the machine running the code and reverse the bytes manually as necessary. The code below should work, but you will only be able to convert one int or float at a time.

```
define('BIG_ENDIAN', pack('L', 1) === pack('N', 1));

function pack_int32s_be($n) {
    if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
        return pack('l', $n); // that's a lower case L
    }
    return strrev(pack('l', $n));
}
function pack_int32s_le($n) {
    if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
        return strrev(pack('l', $n));
    }
    return pack('l', $n); // that's a lower case L
}
function pack_double_be($n) {
    if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
        return pack('d', $n);
    }
    return strrev(pack('d', $n));
}
function pack_double_le($n) {
    if (BIG_ENDIAN) {
        return strrev(pack('d', $n));
    }
    return pack('d', $n);
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't handle systems that don't use twos complement signed integers and IEEE 64 bit doubles. There are very few systems where that is the case. If they need to be supported, the only way is to write a custom pack function for those systems.

Comment: Really? 'l' isn't even guaranteed to return 2's complement? That's dumb if so. That said, I don't think any computer on which PHP will run uses 1s complement, though, so that was silly of you to bring that up. Perl is used on machines with are neither BE nor LE, so I imagine PHP is too, so that is a real problem if he wants portability to wherever PHP runs.

Comment: As for IEEE 64-bit doubles, they are extremely common, and the number is only going to go up. I don't know if PHP uses them, but your code fails at the requested portability if it does.

Comment: PHP does use 64 bit IEEE doubles (at least on the machine I tested), and the code does work for them. The problem is that pack makes no guarantee about the size or format ("machine dependent size and representation").

Comment: That question wasn't whether PHP can use doubles. The question is whether PHP can use quads. Your testing doesn't reveal anything useful at all. Keep in mind PHP's docs specifically says it doesn't always use doubles.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The PHP version I tested used 64 bit double precision floating point, but there is no guarantee about the size. I think we are both saying the same thing. :-)

Comment: When I said as for "As for IEEE 64-bit doubles,", I meant "As for floating points numbers other than 64-bit doubles". Very common. Yet, you say your code won't work for them. PHP's docs specifically says it doesn't always use doubles, so it seems your code isn't portable. So no, we're not saying the same thing. I've repeatedly said "this might not be portable" and you says "well, it works on my system". Not the same thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28324/discussion-between-mcrumley-and-ikegami)

Comment: Thanks for the possible solutions and an interesting debate. I'm sorry to say much of this goes over my head and I think I have bitten off more than I can chew. I was really hoping for a simple solution using a particular pack format - this is clearly not possible. I think for the moment I'll abandon the shape file creation idea and look at an alternative such as exporting to KML. Not as 'good' but a much simpler solution (I think!). Thanks again. Steve

Answer (score 5):

If PHP doesn't support it, you could implement your own.

```
function pack_int32be($i) {
   if ($i < -2147483648 || $i > 2147483647) {
      die("Out of bounds");
   }
   return pack('C4',
      ($i >> 24) & 0xFF,
      ($i >> 16) & 0xFF,
      ($i >>  8) & 0xFF,
      ($i >>  0) & 0xFF
   );
}

function pack_int32le($i) {
   if ($i < -2147483648 || $i > 2147483647) {
      die("Out of bounds");
   }
   return pack('C4',
      ($i >>  0) & 0xFF,
      ($i >>  8) & 0xFF,
      ($i >> 16) & 0xFF,
      ($i >> 24) & 0xFF
   );
}
```

The double-precision LE is much harder. Supporting quad-precision system would involve packing the number using `d`, converting it to a binary string, splitting the binary into fields, truncating the fields to the right size if they're too large, concatenating the fields, then converting from binary to bytes.